# Increment date column by VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, increment

if i have a column in excel in following format: 
"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" and i want to increase the hour value by 1. 
I add  1/24 to that cell and is done.

my problem is that files where i need this correction have around 15000 rows and operation is taking around 2 minutes.
the code i use is:

```
Set rngSel = .Range("A2:A10000")
  For Each cell In rngSel
       cell.Value = cell.Value + dif / 24
    Next cell
```

is it possible somehow to do it faster?

Comment: Read the range to a `Variant` array and do the math in memory, then write back to the sheet at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Initial_DateTime As Date
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arr = .Range("A2:A10000")

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

            Initial_DateTime = arr(i, 1)

            arr(i, 1) = DateAdd("h", 1, Initial_DateTime)

        Next i

        .Range("A2:A1000").Value = arr

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it is much quicker to load the range into a matrix and handle the incrementation of the dates in memory. I have built upon your code for the following example.

```
Sub IncrementDateColumnByVBA()
    Dim rngSel As Range
    Dim DateArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dif As Byte

    dif = 1

    Set rngSel = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10")

    'Write range to a matrix
    DateArray = rngSel.Value

    'Loop matrix
    For i = LBound(DateArray) To UBound(DateArray)
        DateArray(i, 1) = DateArray(i, 1) + dif / 24
    Next i

    'Write matrix to worksheet
    rngSel.Value = DateArray

End Sub
```